# NetBeans debugger ignores breakpoints

Tags: java, maven, debugging, netbeans-15

I have a problem with the debugger in a Maven project in NetBeans 15. The debugger starts, but it totally ignores my breakpoints. As I think, the problem is in the "Action" section:

```
<actions>
    <action>
        <actionName>run</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>package</goal>
            <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <runfx.args>-jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"</runfx.args>
        </properties>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>debug</actionName>
        <preAction>build-with-dependencies</preAction>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>package</goal>
            <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java</goal>
            <goal>javafx:run@ide-debug</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
            <runfx.args>-jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"</runfx.args>

        </properties>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>profile</actionName>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>javafx:run@ide-profile</goal>
        </goals>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>CUSTOM-jlink</actionName>
        <displayName>jlink</displayName>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <!-- Compile is not needed with javafx-maven-plugin v0.0.5 -->
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>javafx:jlink</goal>
        </goals>
    </action>
</actions>
```

All was ok with the debugger, till I added the following, like:
`<runfx.args>-jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"</runfx.args>`
to the "debug" section and modified the goals. Without these changes, I wasn't able to use a third-party library (SwissEphe) at debugging.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: deleting lines <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java</goal> and <runfx.args>-jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"</runfx.args> from "Actions" make debugger work again normally. But I need those lines... Any suggestions?

Comment: Provide any new information for your question by updating it rather than using comments. It shouldn't be necessary to read the comments at all to fully understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by migration to IntelliJ. Solution for NetBeans not found.